# How to diagnose that socketio port is already in use on nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, port

Simple code to listen on 8080

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
```

doesn't warn me if 8080 is already taken by another application (I can see this by means of netstat -a -b). How should I change this code, so it would warn me if 8080 is already in use?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder) out. It works pretty good :)

Comment: nono, i need to have error message if port is used